# Gallery transition like Twitter

Tags: android

I want to achieve a gallery transition effect like that of Twitter:

https://i.imgur.com/BDytqsq.mp4

How are they doing it? Is it a separate activity or a fragment?

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity

Comment: See http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-1/

Comment: Shared Element Transitions is a way of implementing this type transition in listView and gridView, just try to put shared element transition in onItemClick of list or Grid of your Images.

Comment: my question is more along the lines of -- should i use a fragment or an activity?

Answer (score 0):

You should use shared element transition:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition